# FFI for libusb: linked lists

Tags: racket

The library libusb provides cross platform access to USB devices.
The starting point is to get a list of attached USB devices.
The code below attempts to get such a list from libusb, but crashes.
The problem has something todo with the definition of `libusb_get_device_list`
and the type `_libusb_device_list**` although other things could be wrong too.

How can I define `libusb_get_device_list` correctly?

The documentation for the C function is here: http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html#gac0fe4b65914c5ed036e6cbec61cb0b97

```
#lang racket/base
;;; FFI for libusb version 1.0.

(require ffi/unsafe
         ffi/unsafe/define)

;;; Types

(define _ssize_t _ssize) ; signed version of _size_t

;;; Load the shared library

(define libusb 
  (case (system-type)
    [(macosx) (ffi-lib "/usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.0.dylib")]
    [else     (error "Contact maintainer")]))

;;; Create define-usb which makes it easy to define functions from libusb
(define-ffi-definer define-usb libusb)

; ssize_t libusb_get_device_list(libusb_context *ctx, libusb_device ***list)

(define _libusb_context        (_cpointer/null 'libusb-context))
(define _libusb_device_list**  (_cpointer 'device_list**))

(define-usb libusb_get_device_list (_fun    (ctx               : _libusb_context)
                                            (linked-list       : (_ptr o _libusb_device_list**))
                                         -> (number-of-devices : _ssize_t)
                                         ; output wrapper:
                                         -> (list number-of-devices linked-list)))

; Returns a list of USB devices currently attached to the system.
; Unreference all devices, then free the list using libusb_free_device_list.
; A null context gives the default context.

; (libusb_get_device_list #f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your signature is correct (though your argument name is not quite right—the output parameter is a `NULL`-terminated array, not a linked list). However, libusb requires that you call [`libusb_init`](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__lib.html#ga9517c37281bba0b51cc62eba728be48b), even if you don’t use a context. Calling `libusb_init` with `NULL` will initialize the default context.

You need to either call `libusb_init` with `NULL` to initialize the default context:

```
(define-usb libusb_init/default (_fun (_pointer = #f) -> _int)
  #:c-id libusb_init)

(libusb_init/default)
```

...or call it to produce a context that you can later provide to `libusb_get_device_list`:

```
(define-usb libusb_init (_fun    (ctx    : (_ptr o _libusb_context))
                              -> (status : _int)
                              -> (values ctx status)))

(define-values [ctx status] (libusb_init))
```